# Why is the operation using IEnumerator faster than looping through each array

Tags: c#, ienumerable

//sample program to print the string in reverse,trying two approach.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Message string used for reverse operation
        String messageText = " I am human trying to learn programming";
        String[] sep= {" "};

        //reversing the string using  split and accessing the array in reverse order
        string[] splitedString = messageText.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
        //used to measure the time taken by operation1
        DateTime timer = DateTime.Now;
        for (int index = 0; index < splitedString.Length; index++ )
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", splitedString[index]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The time taken is {0}", (DateTime.Now - timer).TotalMilliseconds);

        //used to measure the time taken by operation2
        timer = DateTime.Now;

        //reversing the string using  in build reverse method  and later emumerating though each element using
        //for each
        IEnumerable<String> rev = splitedString.ToList<string>();
        foreach (string individualText in rev)
            Console.Write("{0} ",individualText);


        Console.WriteLine("The time taken is {0}", (DateTime.Now - timer).TotalMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

//sorry earlier code had the split function in wrong place. sorry for submitting wrong code
//just trying to understand why the IEnumerable is faster.

Comment: Er... even if the numbers would be meaningful (they're not), you're not even attempting to measure the difference between the `for` and the `foreach` variants: you include the time to `Split` in one but not in the other.

Comment: I expect that program to almost always output 0ms. To get proper results you need to take warmup into account and either repeat the test in a loop for at least a second or switch to a high performance counter, i.e. `Stopwatch`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Given how bad the check is, that's not a reasonable expectation. :) It reliably outputs ~21ms vs. ~1ms on my system.

Comment: Probably a warmup effect. Even the Console.Write calls (which are probably the most expensive part) shouldn't be that expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly you are seeing the effect of your CPU's caches: at the start the data and code (including framework code) is not cached, as part of the first operation it is copied into the cache. Thus the first operation's time includes much slower memory access.

To effectively time micro-operations you need to loop over thousands of iterations, and avoid potentially high overhead operations (like IO) that could dominate what you want to time (IO can take many orders of magnitude longer than pure CPU operations).

But: it is extremely unlikely that the difference between these types of operations will be significant: 1. more your program work, 2. make it maintainable, and 3. see if performance targets are met. Only if 3's answer is "no" do you start to profile and measure where things are slow.

Comment: Thanks every one, i tried the same inside a loop and used Stopwatch class to measure the timings. After the first iteration in loop both operation seems to take same time. once again thanks for your inputs